# Possible to use Azure xDrive (PageBlob) with on-premises Windows 2008R2

Tags: virtualization, storage, cloud, drivers, azure

Azure's Windows 2008R2 based hosts currently use blob storage for [something called XDrive.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81413/Windows-Azure-Drives-Part-1-Configure-and-Mounting)

Since this is just a driver and a few other system components, has anyone figured out what files need to be present on a (non Azure hosted) 2008R2 server to mount blob storage as local?

What is needed to mount blob storage as a local drive on my Windows 7 machine or 2008R2 server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mount a page blob (as NTFS drive with drive letter) from outside of Windows Azure. This is only for Compute instances within Windows Azure.

I answered this on StackOverflow as well [[link]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9328792/272109).

Comment: Since the PageBlob technology is HTTPS I simply don't understand why someone hasn't replicated this in their own datacenter (albiet with high latency) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/04/16/using-smb-to-share-a-windows-azure-drive-among-multiple-role-instances.aspx

Comment: The link you have is referencing how to create smb shares across Windows Azure instances, with one of those instances (in Windows Azure Compute, not locally) mounting and sharing a drive. You cannot replicate this functionality locally as it's not an offered feature today.

Comment: I guess the angle I was going is that it appears the functionality can be hacked together to work regardless of the "official" status.  One could get an Azure account, copy the relevant drivers to a Windows 2008R2 instance, and have an unlicensed hack working.  But since you're a respected Azure MVP I'm pretty sure you can't say this or advise on any experiment that attempts to do the same

Comment: I'm a *former* MVP. I now work for Microsoft.